# Where does OneNote save its contents when the file is not reachable at the moment?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

Most of our employees use OneNote with a notebook residing on their network user share. Sometimes, the user share is not reachable, however, OneNote does not seem to have a problem with that: data is still displayed and even saving seems to work for some reason.

Does OneNote cache its data somewhere? Is this a "save" behavior, i.e., there is no work lost if the network share becomes reachable again and has an older state of the work than the cache? What happens if OneNote is exited during a network outage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OneNote never works directly on the cloud. When a notebook is opened,
it is copied to the local cache. OneNote works on that copy, but will periodically
resync with the cloud, if an internet connection is available.

The cache is found at the folder:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneNote\16.0\cache
```

where the part of `16.0` may vary between OneNote versions.

The cached files are in a binary format, not in a readable text format.